# Are there any potential issues when binding an "async" method to a "on" event (e.g. click)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, knockout.js, es6-promise

I have a sync method which is called via click in Knockout.js

I need to do some ajax calls for general purposes.

Now, I don't want to necessarily wrap by click logic in many curly braces, hence why I thought to declare the method as `async` to `await` the Ajax calls.

I searched to find any side effects that might occur with this change but I found none.

So I'm asking here to know if there is any to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

> You risk unhandled rejections, but if your async functions never throw or you intend whatever happens with unhandled rejections in your environment then it’s fine

([@Ry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ry))

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881889/is-there-any-problem-with-using-async-function-as-an-eventemitter-listener) could also be helpful.

TLDR: If your function never throws any exception you should be fine.